# Кастомная аутентификация в Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, auth

Есть необходимость сделать не классическую токеновую аутентификацию через Spring Security, а при помощи протокола с нулевым разглашением. Например, [Фейга-Фиата-Шамира](https://wiki2.org/ru/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B3%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0). Можно ли это сделать?

P.S. По сути дела вопрос сводится к тому, можно ли аутентификацию сделать интерактивной - т.е. не просто отправка токена, а многоразовая взаимная отправка информации и по результатам вынесение решения можно ли аутентифицировать пользователя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На нижнем уровне в спринге обычная аутентификация реализована простым хардкодом - в запросе проверяется наличие параметра `accessToken` или `Authentication` заголовка, начинающегося строкой `Bearer`, после чего по значению токена вытаскивается из БД инфа о юзере, после чего она пишется в `security`-контекст спринга, коий - обычный `Singleton`.

Засим, думаю, ответ на ваш вопрос прост: нельзя стандартными средствами. Если вам нужно что-то минимально отличное от простых стандартов - надо все операции реализовывать вручную. Т.е. вручную прописать логику обмена данными меж клиентом и сервером в нужном вам виде, будь то цепочка `http` запросов или обмен данными чрез сокеты.

Comment: Допустим, а в виде REST сервиса, который будет изменять security-контекст, такое выполнить возможно?
Скажем, завязать его на Bean, который будет сохранять состояние и помнить сколько сделано итераций.

Comment: @Bulbum, насколько я понимаю - да, можно. Правда, если это будут несколько запросов, а не один, то вам надо будет в каком-то месте хранить идентификацию разных клиентских запросов. Т.е. что вот это 2 шаг юзера А, а это - 3 шаг юзера Б. Типа некие промежуточные токены в БД хранить и на клиент отдавать, чтобы по ним в следующмх запросах понимать какой это шаг какого юзера.

Comment: Это очень уместное замечание. Учту, спасибо.